# In React Project, how to change and customize node modules

Tags: reactjs, node-modules

I have a requirement to customize/change the node-module in the create react app project. As a practice we are not pushing or storing node_modules and it is driven by package.json. Can you please suggest how to use the customized node_module inside the project ?

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to to push it to your repository? If you are using git take a look at `.gitignore`.

Comment: In that case it push all the node modules. Is that be ok, if I push only the modified node modules to the repo?

Comment: Ah, do you mean you are modifying the content of certain packages and you want to check those in? You could create an exception rule for those specifc packages. Another route would be to create a fork of the project and publish your own version to an npm feed.

Comment: Ok. Sure. awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik you have two options.

1. Create a .gitignore file with exceptions for the packages you want to check in.

```
node_modules
!node_modules/<package_name> //repeat for every package
```

2. Create a fork of the project you want to modify, this ofcourse can only be done if this is an open-source project. And publish the package to a (private?) npm feed. If you want to publish it to the public npm feed you will have to change the name in the `package.json`.